# Field Calculator python to Python code

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, cursor, pycharm

I am trying to convert a python code from field calculator to arcpy (pycharm).

All i am wanting to do is convert the below python code into a way python in pycharm will read it.

```
!Owner_Ab!.title()
```

This is my attempt however it does not work.

```
feature_class = CAD_WA
FukMoO = 'Owner_Ab'


with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(feature_class, FukMoO) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[0] = row[0].title
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: What happens when you run the code that you have presented?  Any error message is likely to give a hint as to its cause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not showing all your code but

`row[0].title` should be `row[0].title()`

```
row = ('does not work',)

print('1:', row[0].title)
print('2:', row[0].title())

1: <built-in method title of str object at 0x7f4ae3465570>
2: Does Not Work
```